# Highlight string in php

Tags: php

I would like to use CSS to style a piece of string in my php echo line.

I am using

```
echo "Tell you a" <span style="colour:red;"> secret </span>
```

Could you please show me a way i can add some CSS to the word Secret?
Thanks.

I need to use CSS to make this work.

Comment: I am not trying to combine two strings together!

Comment: Then write it in one string.

Comment: like this? echo "Tell you a <span style="colour:red;"> secret </span>"; ?

Comment: Almost just change the double quotes in side the string into single quotes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this with no luck; echo "Tell you a <span style='colour:red;'> Secret </span>";

Comment: Check [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ee67f2a8f3350faa1a5f)

Comment: Won't tell you but `color` not `colour`